# POP3 get domain name for autorization

Tags: domain, domain-name, pop3

I have pop3 server and 2 domain names. In pop3 session how nca i know what the user's domain connected?

We have:

C: user name

S: OK+

C: pass password

S: OK+

We have only user name. Where can i get user domain name?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't in there.  If you knew your usernames would be unique across domains you could just look up what domain a user belongs to, but there's no way to know other than that.

Also, some notes about what software you are using would be helpful in answering you, in case there's a feature of whatever you use.